# Facebook Graph API - page/feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am bringing in community pages' public posts, But one of the pages I am using through the API is returning users' "Posts To Page"

I've taken a look at other pages' on Facebook and they are returning publicly posted posts. Does anyone have any idea what the cause of this might be?

I suspect it may be a permissions issue?

[image: Graph API Explorer]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the API documentation /posts is what you are looking for:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed

> **`/{page-id}/posts`** shows only the posts that were published by this page.

Comment: Cheers @GroovyCarrot what I do find strange is that a new item has been posted by the page admin and that has appeared in the stream.

Comment: To be honest I've had this issue before, my solution at the time was to iterate through the feed output and only output posts by the page id. I assumed they had fixed the flaw with this from the documentation as it wasn't around when I had this issue